# Undefined in promise when dispatch action on Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm trying to fetch api data from back end. The data appears, it's just that there is an error in the console.
the program looks fine, but the console error bothers me.
how do i handle this?

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wx7c.png)

im trying to get state.employees with computed and assign in to results.

```js
setup() {
  const store = useStore();  
  /* token state */
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  // dispatching action getEmployees in modules employees
  /* Dispatching for retrieving user info */
  store
    .dispatch("user/retrieveUserInfo", token)
    .then((res) => {})
    .catch((error) => {
       console.log("Cannot Retrieve Data");
    });
  store.dispatch("employees/getEmployees");
   
  /*
     get all data employees from vuex  
  */
    
  const results = computed(() => {
     return store.state.employees;
  });
  const user = computed(() => {
    return store.state.user;
  });
    
  return {
    results,
    user,
  };
},
```

**employees.js.**

```js
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  namespaced: true,
    state() {
      return {
        employees: {},
      };
    },
    mutations: {
      setEmployees(state, payload) {
        state.employees = payload;
      },
    },
    actions: {
      async getEmployees({ commit }) {
        return await axios
          .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees`)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response.data.success) {
              commit("setEmployees", response);
            }
            // resolve(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            // reject(error);
          });
      },
    },
  };
```

Admin.vue

```js
<script>
import {
  computed,
  onBeforeMount,
  onMounted,
  reactive,
  ref,
  toRefs,
} from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import Modal from "../../Modal.vue";
export default {
  components: { Modal },
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const router = useRouter();
    const isVisible = ref("");

    /* token state */
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    // dispatching action getEmployees in modules employees
    /* Dispatching for retrieving user info */

    store.dispatch("user/retrieveUserInfo", token).then((res) => {});
    store.dispatch("employees/getEmployees");
    const showModal = () => {
      isVisible.value = true;
    };
    const closeModal = () => {
      isVisible.value = false;
    };
    /* 
    get all data employees from vuex  
    */
    const logout = computed(() => {
      store.dispatch("auth/loggedOut", token).then((res) => {
        router.push({
          name: "login",
        });
      });
    });
    const results = computed(() => {
      return store.state.employees;
    });
    const profil = computed(() => {
      return store.state.user;
    });

    return {
      results,
      profil,
      logout,
      isVisible,
      showModal,
      closeModal,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I can get the data I want from the api, the problem is, why does the console have an undefined error? so maybe it's not related to the API, so I don't include the source code of the API.

Comment: Can you add the Admin.vue code also? The place where the error is coming

Comment: Edit your question - add components template + JSON your `api/employees` API route returns...

Comment: Please, post the error as text, it doesn't benefit from being an image. The code you posted doesn't contain the place where the error occurs. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry this is my first time trying to ask on stackoverflow